# How can I get last function name and parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Such as:

```
def A(a):
    print a

def B(func):
   ...

if __name__ = "__main__":
    B(A(a))
```

I want get the message:

```
A(a)
```

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, this is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this, but the module [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) can help here:

```
import inspect

def A(a):
    print(a)

def B(func, arg):
    print('{}({})'.format(func.__name__, inspect.getargs(func.__code__)[0][0]))
    return func(arg)

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    a = 1
    B(A, a)
```

Output:

```
A(a)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since you specifically stated that you use Python 3, I have to comment that your syntax is incorrect. Parenthesis are required for `print(a)` since Python 3 changed `print` to a function. Also, there should be a double equal sign in the second to last line, because you are checking an equality.

This code should work perfectly fine:

```
def A(a):
    print(a)

def B(func):
   ...

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    a = 1
    B(A(a))
```

where you can assign anything you want to `a` before printing it.

EDIT: After looking at the question again, I am quite unsure why you would expect/want the output to be `"A(a)"`. You pass a function that is called `A()` to function `B()`, usually to do something with it.
You can get the name of the function `A()` out by rewriting `B` to:

```
def B(func):
    print(func.__name__)
```

However, as far as I know, there is no way for function `B()` to know which parameters function `A()` can take in this scenario.

Comment: Then you should maybe consider accpeting somebody's answer such that this question is marked as 'answered'.

Comment: Below code is my resolve:
import inspect
    stack_info = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe().f_back)
This stack_info contain last function info